# Странный прямоугольник при открытии меню

Tags: html, css

На [странице](http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/dev/AS/) при открытии меню на телефоне в углу появляется странный прямоугольник, непонятно, откуда взявшийся. Этот же прямоугольник есть и в эмуляторе в Google Chrome и Yandex.Browser. Что это может быть? Может быть сталкивались с такой проблемой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: такого прямоугольника не видно ttp://mobiletest.me/htc_one_emulator/?u=http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/dev/AS/

Comment: @Arsen если тестировать через онлайн сервис - его не видно. но, с мобильного устройства или на ПК в хроме, в режиме тестирования адаптива - прямоугольник есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в 'HTML' после `<div class="lang_block"></div>` идёт AFTER `.clearfix:after` вот от него и у вас прямоугольник показывает.
При тестировании чере google chrome может показать, но в реальном мобильном - не должно показыватся.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в медиа запросах для малого разрешения экрана задано фоновое изображение, но ему не задано повторение, вот этот квадратик и показывается всего 1 раз, допишите `background-repeat`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px){
    header nav {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0;
        width: 240px;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
        background: url(../images/page__background.jpg) #f2f2f2;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: -280px;
        z-index: 9999;
        background-repeat: repeat;/*вот эту строчку*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Фоновое изображение размером 100*100 и оно повторяется (это видно на блоке навигации).